# Throw exception only for last item in RxJava chain

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a list of wifi adresses in my Android app. Also, there is WifiManager that accept address and do connect if possible. Connection procedure is RxJava Completable, that throws exception in case of connection failure. How can i check all adresses 1 by 1, and throw exception only if last adress failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just suppress errors in all but the last `Completable`

```
List<String> addresses = ...
int s = address.size();

Flowable.range(0, s)
.flatMapCompletable(index -> {
    Completable c = manager.checkAddress(addresses.get(index));
    if (index != s - 1) {
        c = c.onErrorComplete();
    }
    return c;
}, false, 1)
.subscribe(...)
```